# What is the purpose of distributed testing in Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

What is distributed testing in Jmeter?
What is its actual purpose?

I searched and read a lot about master/slave concept in Jmeter and I know how it can be done, but what is its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed testing is to be used when you reach the limits of a machine in terms of CPU, Memory, Network:

- It can be used within one machine (many JVMs on one machine), if you reach the limits of one **reasonable** JVM in terms of Memory & CPU
- It can be used accross many machines ( 1 or many JVMs on 1 or many Machines)

**BUT** before using it ensure you really need it, read this:

- http://www.dzone.com/links/r/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is limitation of a single normal configuration machine to generate large user load test. So we use distributed load testing to use multiple machines for generating the load wherein you rightly said we used master slave configuration.
For more about distributed load testing and other things about JMeter you can refer the link-
[Distributed load testing with JMeter](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/distributed-load-testing-in-jmeter.html)

Comment: Article shows usage in GUI mode, this is to be avoided

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of the distributed testing in jmeter is load distribution. That means: think you want to generate a load of 3000 users to an application, Jmeter have no limitation in creating number of users but the limitation is our hardware or CPU. We assume that because of our CPU limitation we can send only 1000 request from one computer. If I need to send 3000 requests means I need 3 systems. this distributed test will give cumilated result of 3000 users in one file as an output.

If your system is well and using http sampler or smpt you do not feel to use distributed to generate loads. But If you start using Samplers like Webdriver sampler or something which gives heavy load CPU you need to go for distributed. Because for example: Webdriver sampler you are running then only 10 to 15 users can be started in one system, if you need more users you need to go for distributed and there is no other good option other than distributed

Answer (score 0):

It is used to generate load from a different location or to generate more load than you could from a single computer.